# Python errors using "%matplotlib inline"

Tags: python

I am working on a python program that using matplotlib. I have it installed into the program, but when I try to add "%matplotlib inline" I am getting syntax errors.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline
```

When I test with just these two lines, I am returning a syntax error on the "%". I have tried reinstalling matplotlib through pip to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you actually using a Jupyter environment? What error exactly?

Comment: My system freezes whenever I attempt to use Jupyter. I am using IDLE and have had no issues with any modules previous to this one. The error I am recieving shows "Invalid syntax" and highlights the "%"

Comment: You can't use "Jupiter magic" if you're _not using Jupyter_.

Answer (score 1):

```
%matplotlib inline
```

is not a Python command, it's so-called IPython [magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html) that is working in Jupyter or pure IPython environment only. IDLE doesn't support it, and it cannot show you figures inline.

Comment: Ah that makes sense why it wouldn't be working, thank you.

Comment: @MichaelDebo you can accept an answer if it solves your problem